# 'Collapsed' is not a valid value for the 'System.Windows.UIElement.Visibility' property on a Setter

Tags: xaml, resourcedictionary

I'm struggling with something but I know what is going wrong, just not why.

The following entry in my resource dictionary works

```
 <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
```

I need to make this dynamic and bind the value to a static property, and this is where it is failing.

```
<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{x:Static loc:StateMachine.CollaspseOrVisibleString}" />
```

and returns the following exception

> 'Collapsed' is not a valid value for the 'System.Windows.UIElement.Visibility' property on a Setter.

The static property is definitely returning the string "Collapsed" so I'm lost as to why it's not valid.

Comment: Check the types. From what I see I can guess property "CollaspseOrVisibleString" has type System.String while it should have  System.Windows.Visibility type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind to something that returns a value of the Visibility enumeration type, not a string:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

i.e. change your StateMachine.CollapseOrVisible property return type to 'Visibility' and have it return Visibility.Collapsed (the enumeration value, not the string)

Comment: ...Of course, when I set the value in XAML to "Collapsed", it's just (effectively) XML! I thought it was accepting a string. D'oh! Thanks.